# Play Framework, bind Akka Typed actor without create Provider

Tags: java, playframework, akka-typed

I am trying to implement **Akka Typed** from **Akka Classic**.
In newest document [Akka Classic](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaAkka#Dependency-injecting-actors) and [Akka Typed](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AkkaTyped#Runtime-dependency-injection)

My actor

```
public class ConfiguredActor extends AbstractActor {

  private Config configuration;
  // many other inject components

  @Inject
  public ConfiguredActor(Config configuration) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
    // many other inject components
  }

  ...
}
```

`ConfiguredActor` have many **inject components**. In Classic way, I just need bind an actor

```
bindActor(ConfiguredActor.class, "configured-actor");
```

and **inject components** inside `ConfiguredActor` will be injected by **Guice**. like this [doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaAkka#Dependency-injecting-child-actors) said

> Guice will do that for us, providing an implementation that not only passes our key parameter, but also locates the Configuration dependency and injects that

But in Typed way. I have to provide that components when bind actor

> For the object-oriented style you must write a Provider for your ActorRef and bind it

Is there anyway to bind an actor in Typed way without create `Provider`. Thanks

I am using Play framework version 2.8.2, Akka typed version 2.6.0